# how to how to select random object and the length of the random selected object at the same time

Tags: javascript

I made an array object and a function to choose randomly. I want to get the length of (the random object which has selected from random function) and itself in *one static function*. Also I want to get the same selected object.length.

I did the return like its an array object

```
what i expect
17 or 22 or etc
17 or 22 or etc
```

I always want the same number no matter what.

```
var roastAboutUglyLvl1 = {
  rt1: "ugly very poor roast",
  rt2: "ugly poor roast",
  rt3: "ugly medium roast",
  rt4: "ugly strong roast",
  rt5: "ugly very strong roast"
}

function randomRoast(obj){
      var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        return {
          roast: obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]],
          thelength:obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]].length,
          check:function(){
            if(this.roast.length == this.thelength){
              return this.thelength;
            }else{
              return "didn't match";
            }
          }
        }
    };


var func = randomRoast(roastAboutUglyLvl1); 
while(func.check() != "didn't match"){
  var func = randomRoast(roastAboutUglyLvl1); 
  console.log(func.roast.length)
  console.log(func.thelength)
}
```

Comment: What is `<< 0` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would probably avoid using bitwise operators, `>>` or `<<`, as those are pretty uncommon and always difficult to reason about. To achieve the same thing you could do `Math.round(keys.length * Math.random())`.

Comment: @connexo in this context `Math.floor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i always want the same number ,no matter what

No, what you'd want to do is storing the randomly generated number, key or value and use that to create the object that you return.
Not to use `Math.random()` multiple times and trying to bend it so it return the same *now not even closely* random number twice.

```js
var roastAboutUglyLvl1 = {
  rt1: "ugly very poor roast",
  rt2: "ugly poor roast",
  rt3: "ugly medium roast",
  rt4: "ugly strong roast",
  rt5: "ugly very strong roast"
}

// get a random item from an Array is a quite common task,
// it's fine to write a reusable function for that.
function sample(array) {
  if (array && array.length) {
    return array[ Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length) ];
  }
  return void 0; //just to be explicit for a beginner
}

function randomRoast(obj) {
  var roast = sample( Object.values(obj) );
  
  return {
    roast: roast,
    thelength: roast.length,
    check: function() {
      if (this.roast.length === this.thelength) {
        return this.thelength;
      } else {
        return "didn't match";
      }
    }
  }
};


var func = randomRoast(roastAboutUglyLvl1);
console.log(func.roast, func.roast.length, func.thelength);
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want it , thx. what is if(array){}  what do you mean by that?

Comment: @mhdHD `if (array && array.length)` is a general safeguard that `array` is not falsy *(like `null` or `undefined`)* and that it has a `length`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is next:

`roast: obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]]` Selects one random object

`thelength:obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]].length` Selects another random object

You want to select the same object for both properties so you should use the same random number for selection.

And also avoid using `>>` for generating a random number, there is a simpler solution.

Here is your updated `randomRoast` function:

```
function randomRoast(obj){
      var keys = Object.keys(obj);
      var randNum = Math.random();
        return {
          roast: obj[keys[ Math.floor(randNum  * keys.length) ]],
          thelength:obj[keys[ Math.floor(randNum  * keys.length) ]].length,
          check:function(){
            if(this.roast.length == this.thelength){
              return this.thelength;
            }else{
              return "didn't match";
            }
          }
        }
    };
```