# JS displaying strings in array

Tags: javascript

I have created an array

```js
var array1 = new Array("jack", "kaziu", "wladek");
var display = Math.floor((Math.random() * array1.length));
console.log(display)
```

I cannot figure out how to display characters instead of numbers (array1's length). Appreciate for help.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array) and [Get random item from JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to how to select random object and the length of the random selected object at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170525/how-to-how-to-select-random-object-and-the-length-of-the-random-selected-object)

Comment: `display` gets a random index. Just use `array1[display]`

Answer (score 2):

Index the array with your calculated index:

```js
const array1 = new Array("jack", "kaziu", "wladek");
const display = array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)];

console.log(display);
```